# Python:Can't find string in Source Code

Tags: python

Ok.This is my first question here
So I'm trying to make this program which searches for the phrase "You have an error" in the HTML source code.The problem is when I try

```
    html_data=urllib2.open(site).read()
    if html_data.find(string):
       print "It's found"
```

It doesn't find it..Although when I print html_data it is found in there with no tags whatsoever.
Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Is it just me? Or is it pure irony that a broken script refuses to find "You have an error"! :)

Comment: Code seems OK, except that you want to compare the result of `find` to see if it's greater than *or equal to* 0 (not just testing its truthiness, since 0 is a valid string index but is not a true value). Can you post an example of the HTML that you're searching?

Comment: He is looking for the string "You have an error". If @Cameron is right, then if that string is at the start of a line, it will not be found. Test for `html_data.find(string)>=0`

Comment: Aside: instead of `.find(s) >= 0`, if you don't care about the location, it's more idiomatic to write `if s in html_data:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.find()` returns the index (or -1 if not found). Thus the following is incorrect:

```
if html_data.find(string):
```

It should be:

```
if html_data.find(string) != -1:
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to know the position of the match:

```
if string in html_data:
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot :D
Now I can program in peace again..I owe you one mate :D

Answer (score 1):

Do the upper/lower cases match the page you are looking at? Would you be able to give us the page you are trying to read this from? Because this code seems to work fine:

```
    >>> string = 'You have an error'
    >>> page = """

    You have an error

        """
    >>> if string in page:
        print "It's found"


    It's found
```

Comment: This is the site:
http://belleayremusic.com/concerts/concert.php?id=94'
It's an auto-SQL injection program..Here's the code:
  if self.data.find("You have an error"): 
   print "Found at "+str(self.data.find("You have an error"))
   self.injectable_pt=int(self.injection_point[r])
   self.site=self.site_original
  else:
   print self.data
And for some problem it shows this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'' at line 1
which means that the if clause was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes code is generated dynamically upon javascript loading and execution. In that case you will need to execute the JavaScript to get exactly the same page source as you get from a browser's View Source. You might want to write a browser extension for this, that then if required sends what it finds to your python server. The advantage of that is you get to use a browser's JavaScript vm.

Comment: All true, but the OP says the HTML string that Python already has contains the string (so it's not JS-generated here).

Comment: The OP could in this case be mistaken - as I have been before. Language is a terribly noisy signal one must reach for the likeliest occurrence.

Comment: Though Cameron your idea is just as good. I've been tripped up on that not boolean conditional any number of times. I'd say that us it now that I read the whole thing . Your induction is cetainly flawless On the assumption all facts are true as stated. However sometimes ignoring details turns out to lead the right way. Let's see.

Comment: No this isn't generated with Javascript..It's a simple page :D

Comment: @HasanSaad you should accept Cameron answer if he makes one. I think he was the first to suggest the 'not-boolean' solution.

Comment: @Hasan: You should accept NPE's answer, I was just speculating in my comment :-)

Comment: Sorry..I didn't know about this accept answer thingy..I'm still new to this site :D

Answer (score 0):

`find` method returns -1 if it doesn't find the string, not 0. So, you should use it like

```
if html_data.find(string) != -1:
```